# Python import conflict

Tags: python, package, conflict, python-import

I recently build a Python package and installed it via Debian packager. It is installed on my system so I can use it in other projects. In my new project I have the same name of a package folder, namely, opal. I scanned the web including this site and everything pointed towards using:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
```

Unfortunately, it couldn't resolve the problem, I suspect I am missing a detail.

I am using Python 2.7.3 and here are my project folder structures:

Installed package structure:

```
- opal
     __init__.py
     core.py
```

New Project structure:

```
- opal
  - __init__.py
  - net.py
```

In the new project I cannot do:

```
from opal.core import OpalClient
```

I always get an error that `core` is not found under `opal`!!!

If `__future__` is the solution, can somebody provide me an example. I tried several ways and always got errors. I found this an awkward problem for such a neat language ;)

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Python does *not* merge namespaces without additional help. You have a `opal` top-level package in one place that is being found before the other top-level `opal` package is found. That first package found has `opal.net` as a contained module, but not the `opal.core` module.

You'll need to use a [setuptools namespace setup](http://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#namespace-packages) to enable this behaviour; install your packages with a `setuptools` compliant `setup.py` and let it register and manage namespaces for you.

If you are using Python 3.3 or newer, you can use the new [PEP 420 namespace support](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/), where you'd leave the top-level directory (or directories) *empty* to create a namespace that can then be merged. Also see [*Namespace packages*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#namespace-packages) in the Python 3 import system documentation.

Comment: what is the solution for a debian package? Our users and developers have both options, install the package via apt-get on Linux platforms or the Python way (setuptools).

Comment: I believe that the [Debian Python tools](http://wiki.debian.org/Python/FAQ#Python_eggs) can handle eggs directly. The correct metadata should be present so that the setuptools extensions can find the different `opal` packages and make sure that Python will see them as one top-level namespace.

Comment: In Python 3.3 and later you can make namespaces without setuptools. https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420 But then you can't use Python 3.2 or more importantly Python 2.

Comment: @LennartRegebro: I was in the process of writing something about that already. :-)